# The command exited with code 1

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error like this when i build my project..

`   The command "cd E:\x.AppBuilder\
cd\
cd xWorkingFolder\xDLLReference\

copy /y "E:\x.AppBuilder\x.AppBuilder\bin\x86\Debug\x.AppBuilder.dll" "LocalReference\"" exited with code 1.    x.AppBuilder
`

I am using asp.net. Can any one help me?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: just building my project

Comment: Isn't there anything more in your build output, a few lines up? That line states nothing more than "something has gone wrong"

Comment: Error 19 The command "cd E:\x.AppBuilder\
cd\
cd xWorkingFolder\xDLLReference\

copy /y "E:\x.AppBuilder\x.AppBuilder\bin\x86\Debug\x.AppBuilder.dll" "LocalReference\"" exited with code 1. x.AppBuilder

Comment: This is what i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by just deleting the contents in project properties -> Build events post build event command line.. This error is occurring due to mistakes in contents of this build event command line.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue . I solved it by deleting post built path .